# Can I easily convert an Apache Tomcat application to a WebLogic application?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, oracle, tomcat

I've created an application that uses Spring MVC (Controllers, Request Mapping etc), JSPs (of course) and JDBC calls.  Not a very hard application. I'm unfamiliar with WebLogic and have been researching it, however, the documentation seems scattered and some of wizards and plugins from WebLogic simply don't work after I install them.  Is there an easy way for me to deploy my application to a WebLogic server without having to use the OEPE (Oracle Enterprise Pack for Eclipse ) tools?  Btw I'm on 11g for the WebLogic server as well as the Oracle Database.  If I can do this without OEPE then it would help me get unlocked from using Java 7 as it seems the tools complain and want 6 or 7 and doesn't recognize or like Java 8.

Comment: If you didn't do anything Tomcat specific, then there is no "converting" necessary. Tomcat is a servlet container. WebLogic is a JEE Application Server, which by the spec rules, _includes_ a servlet container.

Comment: How did you end up deploying the application to WebLogic.  Through the web portal or putting the war in the autodeploy directory?

Comment: You can do either, but copying a War to a directory seems pretty easy to me...

Comment: the WAR file can be used the same as the one you used for tomcat, so I think there's no "converting" for that, but you might need to do some settings for jdbc-connections on WebLogic.

Comment: I was reading up on that.  I got my application do deploy so all is good there however I'm sure once I reach the part where I'm doing the jdbc connection that I'll have to configure that in some descriptor and/or in the server settings.